# Listview and List<class>

Tags: android, listview

I have below list of send class

```
 list = fetchdata.queryBuilder().selectColumns("fullname","phonenumber","showtext").query();
```

How can I show this in my `ListView` that has 3 `TextView`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up a `BaseAdapter` with a `getView` that sets each column to a specific `TextView`.

Read this for further detail :
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters

> A ListView instance requires an Adapter to feed it with data contained
>   in row views.

Your `query()` command above gives you a `Cursor` object which you can use in a `CursorAdapter` to populate a `ListView`.

Comment: can you explain your answer with example?

Comment: @user2580975 I added a link to a text that you could read to make things clear. The answer is meant to guide you, because you have not provided a lot of code and I'm not sure what you have tried.

Comment: can i put my list into cursor??

Comment: @user2580975 I believe the `query()` gives you a `Cursor` which you can use in a `CursorAdapter`

Comment: i use ormlite that dont give a cursor to me,and give a list of my class to me. tnx for your help

Comment: @user2580975 Well there is a lot of adapters, maybe try a `ListAdapter`, but if all else fails you can simply make your own adapter from `BaseAdapter`. All you have to do is implement a few methods, try reading the docs and google some tutorials. I'm just trying to guide you in the right direction.